# amsart, setspace, and footnotes

Tags: footnotes, amsart, setspace

When I use the `setspace` package in an [`amsart`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) document, the indentation of footnotes is messed up; the first-line indent is lost, with everything pushed to the left.

Sample document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
Hello.\footnote{There.}
\end{document}
```

Compare the placement of the footnote text when the second line is included vs. excluded. This does not occur in the `article` class, for which the inclusion of `setspace` appears to make no difference.  I experience the issue on both MacTeX (from MacPorts) on Max OS 10.6, and on MiKTeX on a Windows XP machine.

How can I keep `setspace` from messing up the footnote indentation when using `amsart`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setspace redefines `\@footnotetext`. You could save that command in your own macro and restore it after loading setspace:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\let\std@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\usepackage{setspace}
\let\@footnotetext\std@footnotetext
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello.\footnote{There.}
\end{document}
```

This is a method that can generally be used for such workarounds regarding undesired changes by packages.