# Footnote indentation with amsart and setspace

Tags: indentation, footnotes, line-spacing, amsart, setspace

A follow-up to this question: [amsart, setspace, and footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/amsart-setspace-and-footnotes)

As explained there, using the `setspace` package in an `amsart` document removes the indentation in the first lines of footnotes. This is apparently because of the way `setspace` redefines `\@footnotetext`. But the solution offered earlier, which is to save this command in a macro and restore it after loading `setspace`, has the undesirable feature of applying the line-spacing settings for the main text to the footnotes as well. On its own, the `\setstretch` function only affects the line-spacing of the main body. But using the `\@footnotetext` fix makes it affect the line-spacing of footnotes too. So, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\makeatletter
\let\std@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
\let\@footnotetext\std@footnotetext
\makeatother
\begin{document}
The main text is double-spaced thanks to our use of the setstretch function.\footnote{But now this footnote is double-spaced just like the main text. How do I fix this?}
\end{document}
```

results in a double-spaced footnote. Inserting `\usepackage{footmisc}` after `\makeatother` in the above example makes the footnote single-spaced again, but it seems to indent the first line of each footnote a little too much (more than the main text is indented). I can adjust the first-line footnote indent by using, e.g., `\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.1em}` after `\usepackage{footmisc}`, but I don't know how wide the standard main-text `amsart` indent is, so I don't know how to make it match the main text exactly. And this still leaves the problem of how to adjust the indentation of subsequent paragraphs within a footnote.

Does anyone know what the proper relationship is between main-text indentation and footnote first-line indentation in `amsart`, as well as that between the first line of a footnote and the first lines of subsequent paragraphs within that footnote? And how do I get these to line up without screwing up the line-spacing of the footnote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick of `setspace` is adding

```
\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\reset@font
```

in front of the code for `\@footnotetext` (but it uses the standard code); so we do it to the code provided by `amsart`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% save the code for \@foonotetext
\let\std@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
% restore the code for \@footnotetext
\let\@footnotetext\std@footnotetext
% now patch it
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {\normalfont}
  {\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\reset@font\normalfont}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the main text is single-spaced too, no matter what I set \setstretch to.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the wrong line in `amsart.cls`

Comment: That works and is much more elegant than getting footmisc involved. Thanks.